# Css Animation not working smoothly

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I tried to search everywhere and ended up that translate3D helps in smoothing animation but still it isn't working .. Here's the code :

```
.circle {
    z-index: 15;
    position: relative;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: #8bc34a;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 24px;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 37%;
    float: right;
    right: 3%;
    font-size: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-14px, 28px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-14px, 28px, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out
}

.circle .main {
    visibility: visible;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 12px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out .3s;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out .3s
}
.circle.active {
    padding-top: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 15;
    margin: -1px;
    right: 2px;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}
.circle .close {
    border-radius: 40px;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    left: 4px;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out
}
.circle.active .main {
    visibility: hidden;
    left: 4px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out
}
```

The Html with Php:

```
 <div class="container1">
    <div class="circle <?php echo $shyt?>">
        <div class="close">
         <i class="icon-cancel xcv" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       </div>
        <div class="main1">
       <div class="main <?php echo $ytmain?>">
          <i class="icon-share" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       </div>


      <div class="social">
        <div class="btn facebookbtn">
         <a class="linkso" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://mp3chest.com/mp3/<?php echo $scrren?>&description=Hey There, Download 
 <?php echo $op90?> Mp3 For Free in the Best Quality easily Here. Just Click On Download Mp3 And Direct Download Will Start&picture=<?php echo $art300?>" target="_blank"> <i class="icon-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn twitterbtn">
          <a class="linkso" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https://mp3chest.com/mp3/<?php echo $scrren?>&text=Hey There, Download 
 <?php echo $op90?> Mp3 For Free Here" target="_blank">  <i class="icon-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn googlebtn">
          <a class="linkso" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://mp3chest.com/mp3/<?php echo $scrren?>" target="_blank">  <i class="icon-gplus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It works smoothly on my pc but not on my mobile redmi note 4 and note 3 it just glitches while expanding . please help

Sample Url : https://mp3chest.com/mp3/Cuebrick-feat-KARRA---Smoke--Fire-OUT-NOW (Just Click On The Share Button And That's The Animation Part).

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between your pc and mobile is the hardware configuration. It can be your mobile's configuration not being able to render it smoothly. Try it on another mobile,or maybe an upgraded one.

Comment: OK ... but it's also doing this in redmi note 3